# How to validate JSON data with ng-pattern

Tags: html, angularjs, json, regex

My app pulls json data and randomises the results on click, how can i validate each result that get's generated and state whether the value is valid/invalid?

view

```
  <div ng-controller="idCtrl">
    <button ng-click="randomize()">Random value on click</button>    
    <p>Id Number: <span data-ng-bind="RandomId.number"></span></p>
    <p>Valid?: <span></span> </p>
 </div>
```

json

```
[
    {"number": "8607025402081"},
    {"number": "8501016184086"},
    {"number": "6104053425672"},
    {"number": "8909025012083"},
    {"number": "2222222222222"},
    {"number": "8888888888888"},
    {"number": "0000000000000"},
    {"number": "9999999999999"}
]
```

script

```
var idApp = angular.module('idApp', []);
idApp.controller('idCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.regex = '(((\d{2}((0[13578]|1[02])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|(0[13456789]|1[012]) (0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|02(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))|([02468][048]|[13579][26])0229))(( |-)(\d{4})( |-)(\d{3})|(\d{7}))'; 

    $scope.randomize = function(){

    $http.get('js/idnumbers.json')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.idnumber = data;
            var randomIDIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.idnumber.length);
            $scope.RandomId = $scope.idnumber[randomIDIndex];
            console.log(data);
        })};
}]);
```

Comment: can't you just use `JSON.parse()` to validate the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ngPattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) is used with input controls most often. If you wanted to use ngPattern you could do something like the following. However, the invalid values are not being put in the text box. I assume this is  because they are...invalid.

Note: I modified your regex from a string to a RegExp.

```js
var idApp = angular.module('idApp', []);
idApp.controller('idCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {

    var data = [{
      "number": "8607025402081"
    }, {
      "number": "8501016184086"
    }, {
      "number": "6104053425672"
    }, {
      "number": "8909025012083"
    }, {
      "number": "2222222222222"
    }, {
      "number": "8888888888888"
    }, {
      "number": "0000000000000"
    }, {
      "number": "9999999999999"
    }];
    $scope.regex = /(((\d{2}((0[13578]|1[02])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|(0[13456789]|1[012]) (0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|02(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))|([02468][048]|[13579][26])0229))(( |-)(\d{4})( |-)(\d{3})|(\d{7}))/;

    $scope.randomize = function() {
      //make your HTTP call here
      $scope.idnumber = data;
      var randomIDIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.idnumber.length);
      $scope.RandomId = $scope.idnumber[randomIDIndex];
      console.log($scope.form.theInput.$valid);
    };

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="idApp">
<div ng-controller="idCtrl">
  <form name="form">
    <button ng-click="randomize()">Random value on click</button>    
    <p>Id Number: <input name="theInput" ng-pattern="regex" ng-model="RandomId.number"></input></p>
    <p>Valid?: <span>{{form.theInput.$valid}}</span> </p>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Since ngPattern is limited to input boxes you may want to just use good ol' JavaScript to accomplish the validation. E.g.,

```js
var idApp = angular.module('idApp', []);
idApp.controller('idCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    var data = [{
      "number": "8607025402081"
    }, {
      "number": "8501016184086"
    }, {
      "number": "6104053425672"
    }, {
      "number": "8909025012083"
    }, {
      "number": "2222222222222"
    }, {
      "number": "8888888888888"
    }, {
      "number": "0000000000000"
    }, {
      "number": "9999999999999"
    }];
    var regex = /(((\d{2}((0[13578]|1[02])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|(0[13456789]|1[012]) (0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|02(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))|([02468][048]|[13579][26])0229))(( |-)(\d{4})( |-)(\d{3})|(\d{7}))/;

    $scope.randomize = function() {

      //http call here
      $scope.idnumber = data;
      var randomIDIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.idnumber.length);
      $scope.RandomId = $scope.idnumber[randomIDIndex];
      $scope.valid = regex.test($scope.RandomId.number);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="idApp">
  <div ng-controller="idCtrl">
    <button ng-click="randomize()">Random value on click</button>
    <p>Id Number: <span data-ng-bind="RandomId.number"></span>
    </p>
    <p>Valid?: {{valid}} 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you Rodger